# How to know if alarm set on my application?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I made a simple application according [this manual](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

But I don't want to receive alarm intent all the time, so I add switch for cancelling alarm. When I switch it on alarm starts, when I switch it off alarm cancels. But sometimes I close my app and after restart it doesn't know whether alarm is set or not for check or uncheck this switch.

What is best practices to determine if alarm was set on my application?

Comment: You can save your alarm state somewhere like as SharedPreferences.

Comment: But after reboot app will be thinking that alarm is set, but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no publicly documented way to get scheduled alarms from AlarmManager. If you need this info you have to keep track of them yourself.